# Why are my numbers not adding up using '+='?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to pop numbers from the `ranks` array and add them all up in a counter variable. When I use `+=`, it doesn't add them up, it just sticks the numbers together and returns `10987`. I'm using the `let playerCountArray` variable as a placeholder for the result. Any clues to what's wrong here?

```
const ranks = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
let playerCountArray = [];

playerCountArray += popArr(ranks)

let popArr = (arr) => {
    return arr.pop()
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: you have strings in your array, either store numbers instead or convert it to numbers.

Comment: Voting to close as _Not reproducible or was caused by a typo
While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers._

Comment: Remove the quotes or cast to number when reducing to sum them `const sum = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'].reduce((a,b)=> +a + +b)`

Comment: Thank you, yes I forgot to take out the quotes. I have tried to place the .reduce in the code but unsuccessful. This is what I was trying but throws an error: `playerCountArray += popArr(ranks).reduce((a,b)=> +a + +b)`

Comment: The problem is that the counter is an array and not a number. 
Initialize it as 0 instead of [] and it will work. 

The problem, in general, is the automated casting of types in Javascript. It is a complex topic and I encourage you to look at that in-depth, you will find interesting things there.

Comment: Oh amazing such a small thing has stalled me for hours! Thank you so much! Yes I'll look into that